# create canned responses in Gmail using Gmail API

Tags: google-apps-script

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446142/gmail-api-canned-responses) which talks about getting a list of available canned responses.

I am looking to programatically **create** canned responses. I am talking about the canned responses in/from the "Canned Responses (Templates)" advanced add-on.

[image]

[image]

I have checked around https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/ but I am not seeing anything.

I assume I have to create a draft, which I can do, but how do I make the draft available for use as a canned response.

Comment: It looks like you create the craft and then choose the "save draft as template" option. ( I don't use this addon).

Comment: Yes. That is how to do it from the UI. I am trying to mimic this behaiour programatically. The canned responses are saved as special types of drafts. They are in the draft folder but hidden. If you make an API call to list all of your drafts it will list the canned responses. So I can get a list of canned responses but I can't figure out how to create them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to manage Canned Responses with the Gmail API or the GmailApp from Appscript. 
Maybe you could create a Sheet with the message content, and use it as "canned response template".

Comment: How would that work? How would an end-user use the data in a sheet to reply to an e-mail thread?

Comment: Sorry, I understood the objective was to create automated emails with the API using drafts.